# Enumeration yielded no result?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

I am trying to filter some objects using linq to enitites and I get an error telling me "Enumeration yielded no results".

on the client side I get a message like this:

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been
>   disposed

I know that these filter values should return some results but it just doesnt work, so Im guessing my query is wrong, can you help please.

```
var mediaChannels =
NeptuneUnitOfWork.MediaChannels
          .FindWhere(m => m.CountryID == CountryID && 
                          m.SonarMediaTypeID == MediaTypeID &&
                          m.SonarMediaTypes.SonarMediaGroupID == MediaGroupID &&
                          m.Name.Contains(search))
          .Select(m => new MediaChannelModel() {
                 ID = m.ID,
                 Name = m.Name,
                 MediaType = m.MediaType.Name,
                 Country = m.Countries.Name,
                 SubRegion = m.Countries.Lookup_SubRegions.Name,
                 Region = m.Countries.Lookup_SubRegions.Lookup_Regions.Name
      });
```

Comment: Is `NeptuneUnitOfWork.MediaChannels` up and running?

Comment: Thanks guys,I had to add a ToList() and also my sql test was wrong so there was no matching data.

Comment: Add ToList() and it will work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My guess is that this runs just fine, then you dispose you context, then you try to access `mediaChannels`.  The problem is that Linq uses deferred execution.  Therefore, you query doesn't really execute until you enumerate `mediaChannels`, which is after you context is disposed.

If you don't want to use deferred execution, then add a `.ToList()` to the end of your query to force it to load right there.

If you want to use deferred execution, then you can't dispose of your context until a later point.

Answer (score 5):

`The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed` is often seen if you send data to the client without saving the data to memory. This can be easily fixed by `.ToList()`-ing your query before sending it to the page

```
var mediaChannels = NeptuneUnitOfWork.MediaChannels
                    .Where(m => m.CountryID == CountryID
                             && m.SonarMediaTypeID == MediaTypeID &&
                             && m.SonarMediaTypes.SonarMediaGroupID == MediaGroupID
                             && m.Name.Contains(search))
                    .Select(m => new MediaChannelModel() {
                                         ID = m.ID,
                                         Name = m.Name,
                                         MediaType = m.MediaType.Name,
                                         Country = m.Countries.Name,
                                         SubRegion = m.Countries.Lookup_SubRegions.Name,
                                         Region = m.Countries.Lookup_SubRegions.Lookup_Regions.Name
                     }).ToList(); // <<-- NOTE this additional method
```